# PySpark - SQL query returns wrong data

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working on implementation of collaborative filtering (using Movielens 20m dataset).

ratings data is looking like this:

```
| userId |  movieId | rating  |  timestamp |
```

ratings are between 1-5 (if a user did't rate a movie it's not appearing in the table).

The following is part of the code:

```
ratings = spark.read.option("inferSchema","true").option("header","true").csv("ratings.csv")
ratings.createOrReplaceTempView("ratings")

ratings.createOrReplaceTempView("ratings")

i_ratings = spark.sql("select distinct userId, case when movieId == 1 then rating else 0 end as rating from ratings order by userId asc ")
```

The SQL query meant to return for movieId == 1 all the ratings it gots from the user, and 0 for users that didn't rate it.

I'm getting the following:[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoAkv.png)

As you can see, if a user didn't rate the movie I'm getting rating = 0 as desired, however for users that did rate the movie i'm getting two rows, one with the actual rating, and another with rating =0.

Checked the ratings.csv dataset, there is no duplicates, that is, every user rated every movie max one time.

Not sure what i'm missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following sql:

```
i_ratings = spark.sql("""
   select
     distinct userId,
     case when rating is not null then rating else 0 end as rating
   from ratings
   where movieId = 1
   order by userId asc
   """)
```

Not sure if this what you want but your screenshot only shows two columns. im guessing you want the following: for a movieid if a user has not provided rating then put 0 else take rating. If this is the case you should filter moveId using where clause.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are right this is what i need. 
However, the query you gave is filtering out users that didn't rate movieId ==1. It gave only users that rate that movie with the actual rating. I need also the other users with rating 0.